# Which ciphers have been defined that use the Keccak sponge?

Tags: encryption, authenticated-encryption, modes-of-operation, keccak, sponge

There seem to have been defined multiple ciphers using the Keccak sponge as building block / primitive. These seem to have escaped public attention, possibly because they have not been standardized and because current ciphers seem to cover most use cases.

I'd like to know:

- Which ones have been defined?
- What are the differences between them?
- And which purpose do they serve?

Do these have any advantages over current ciphers and cipher modes such as AES-CTR, AES-GCM and Salsa20/Poly1305?

Comment: I know at least about Ketje and Keyak. Apparently Xoodoo and related algorithms are not directly based on Keccak.

Answer (score 4):

Since keccak is a relatively large permutation, implementing other symmetric schemes based on keccak besides hashing is concretely expensive. Especially given that AES has hardware acceleration on a lot of chips. However, given the versatility of the [sponge duplex constructions](https://keccak.team/sponge_duplex.html) for symmetric primitives, the Keccak Team designed a separate family of permutations called [Xoodoo](https://keccak.team/xoodyak.html); that are more lightweight, but achieve a smaller security margin.

The family of cryptographic schemes based on Xoodoo is called [Xoodyak](https://keccak.team/xoodyak.html). The Xoodyak constructions are finalists in the [NIST Lightweight Cryptography Competition](https://csrc.nist.gov/Projects/lightweight-cryptography/finalists). The benefit is that since all the schemes are based on the Xoodoo permutation, a much smaller amount of code is required for a variety of symmetric primitives, which make it perfect for IOT devices.

Comment: That's interesting for sure but a it doesn't seem to use Keccak I'm not sure it answers the question directly. I know of at least twi ciphered that do use Keccak.

Comment: Yes, I agree this doesn't directly answer the question. The reason why I mention Xoodyak is because it's a NIST finalist, which is in itself a standardization process.